# Making Jenkins job to choose either of the two repositories through a parameter

Tags: jenkins

I have 2 Jobs which checks out the code from 2 different repository (  A and B resp ).
How can I have a single job which checks out the code from either A or B depending on the parameter  so that i want to reduce the number of jobs in jenkins.I tried the sub version release plugin,but this did not perform what is required by me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't think you can do that -- Jenkins isn't intended to support this particular use case. I would strongly recommend creating two separate jobs -- is there any particular reason you want to reduce the number?

Comment: That is what we have done now ,creating 2 different repository,but we want to run lot of jobs for that monitors repository A, and if any changes then run only 1 particular set of functions and commit those changes to repository A and run some functions which are similar in repository B

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write a script and run it. use parameterized build and configure the parameter. then based on that parameter, clone the repository with the use of script